# Handle interaction between vue fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have prepared a functional code example in JSFiddle of **VUE** field interaction.

https://jsfiddle.net/JLLMNCHR/2a9ex5zu/6/

I have a custom **autocomplete** component that works properly, a normal **input field**, and a **'Load' button** which objetive is to load the value entered in the normal input in the autocomplete field.
This 'load' button is not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">

    <p>Selected: {{test1}}</p>
    <br>
    <div>
      <label>Test1:</label>
      <keep-alive>
        <autocomplete v-model="test1" v-bind:key="1" :items="theItems">
        </autocomplete>
      </keep-alive>
    </div>
    <br>


<label>Display this in 'test1':</label>
<input type="text" v-model=anotherField>
<button type="button" v-on:click="loadField()">Load</button>
<br>

<br>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="displayVals()">Display vals</button>


</div>



<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @input="onChange" v-model="search" 
        @keyup.down="onArrowDown" @keyup.up="onArrowUp" @keyup.enter="onEnter" />
    <ul id="autocomplete-results" v-show="isOpen" class="autocomplete-results">
      <li class="loading" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li v-else v-for="(result, i) in results" :key="i" @click="setResult(result)" 
        class="autocomplete-result" :class="{'is-active':i === arrowCounter}">
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</script>
```

VUE.JS:

```
const Autocomplete = {
  name: "autocomplete",
  template: "#autocomplete",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => []
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      // Let's warn the parent that a change was made
this.$emit("input", this.search);
      // Is the data given by an outside ajax request?
      if (this.isAsync) {
        this.isLoading = true;
      } else {
        // Let's search our flat array
        this.filterResults();
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },

    filterResults() {
      // first uncapitalize all the things
      this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    },
    setResult(result) {    
      this.search = result;
            this.$emit("input", this.search);
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    onArrowDown(evt) {
      if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
      }
    },
    onArrowUp() {
      if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
      }
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter];
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.arrowCounter = -1;
    },
    handleClickOutside(evt) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(evt.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.arrowCounter = -1;
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    items: function(val, oldValue) {
      // actually compare them
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = val;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: {
    autocomplete: Autocomplete
  },
  methods: {
    displayVals() {
        alert("test1=" + this.test1);
    },
    loadField() {
        this.test1=this.anotherField;
    }
  },
  data: {
    test1: '',
    anotherField: '',
        theItems: [ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Tangerine', 'Pineapple']
  }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by1L7aug/) where it is fixed.

When you use v-model on a custom component you need to add a property named `value` and watch it for changes, so it can update the local property `this.search`.